# multiple many to many relationships with bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to determine the best way to represent the following using Bookshelf.js:

I have an `Appointment` model and each `Appointment` has:

- 1 or more `Pet`(s)
- 1 or more `Service`(s)

I'm able to easily represent this using many to many relationships in Bookshelf, which results in three tables: `appointment`, `appointment_pet`, and `appointment_service`.

I now have a new requirement that requires the ability to specify the `Service`(s) that are associated with each `Pet` on a per-appointment basis so that the services associated with a particular pet may be easily retrieved. For example:

**Appointment 1**

- Has 1 Pet
- Has 2 Services (`walk`, `water plants`)
- Pet is associated with `walk` service only.

Getting all services for the `Pet` associated with `Appointment 1` would return `walk`.

Is there an optimal way to represent this scenario using Bookshelf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering that any `Pet` is always associated with a `Service`. In that case, I would structure it like:

[image: ER Diagram]

As in, the `Service` model works as the bridge between an `Appointment` and the `Pet`s. The `Service` can have a pet (e.g. when it's `walk`) or not (e.g. when it's `water plants`). The BookshelfJS model would look like:

```
var Appointment = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  services: function () {
    return this.hasMany('Service');
  },
  pets: function () {
    return this.hasMany('Pet').through('Service');
  },
});
```

A possible issue is that you'll end up with many different `Service`s of the same type, but for different combinations of `Appointment` and `Pet`. This isn't problematic, if there're not many attributes on `Service`. For example, if `Service` has only a `type` attribute.

If you want to add more attributes to `Service`, say a `price`, `time_duration`, etc., you could extract it in its own table, as:

[image: ER diagram with Service as a separate table]

Then the `Service` table will have each type of service with its attributes (e.g. `price`, `time_duration`, ...). The code would look like:

```
var Appointment = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  services: function () {
    return this.hasMany('Service').through('AppointmentService');
  },
  pets: function () {
    return this.hasMany('Pet').through('AppointmentService');
  },
});
```

I would suggest going with the simpler case, and changing that if needed afterwards. You also might need to use the [withPivot](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-withPivot) method to get the values from the relationship tables.

Comment: Hi Vitor - thanks for the solution. This mostly works -- I had to change `hasMany` to `belongsToMany`, which works properly. My only issue is that `withPivot` doesn't seem to have any effect. Regardless if I add `withPivot`, pivot data is returned, but it's missing data. For example, when viewing the pivot data for `pets`, it returns the `id`, `appointment_id` and `pet_id`, but no `service_id`, which is what I really need. I tried doing `this.belongsToMany('Pet').through('AppointmentService').withPivot(['service_id'];`, but it doesn't have any effect. Thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: It seems that `withPivot` doesn't work on a `through` relationship. Not sure if this is a bug or not.

Comment: Are you using the visibility plugin? Remember that pivots are prepended with `_pivot`, so `service_id` in a pivot table would become `_pivot_service_id`.

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this, `withPivot` does not work with `through`. You have to do something like `this.belongsToMany(OtherModel, "pivot_table").withPivot(["col1"]);`